# HealthKit Error "database disk image is malformed"

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm encountering a new error I've never seen before when querying HealthKit. I have not been able to reproduce this error in a test environment but it has been reported by users. The error is:

Error Domain=com.apple.healthd.SQLite Code=1 "(null)"

UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1488aa550 {Error Domain=com.apple.SQLite Code=11 "database disk image is malformed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=database disk image is malformed}}}

I don't have code to post, so my apologies if this question is not quite specific enough, but I am wondering if anyone else has seen this error message, or if there is any known repro or way to recover?

Comment: Seems like an issue from HealthKit internal implementation.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your radar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that the HealthKit database is corrupt and unfortunately there's not much you can do besides reset the device to erase the database. First, though, you should [file a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a bug report.